# Gem: Could not find a valid gem in any repository

Tags: proxy, ruby, gem

my problem is that I installed ruby and gem successfully with no errors, but when I go any further, trying to install any gem, it threw an error: 
`ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '<name>' (>= 0) in any repository` 
One error line only. 
Sorry for this might seem old, I also found lots of similar threads about this problem actually and got most answers are proxy settings. 
But I'm not quite sure, should I turn off the proxy, or turn it on and set it as recommended (and what is it recommended as, if so)? 
My system has proxy turned off, if this helps.

Ok after looking for many solutions, I've found out that my system cannot make connection to `http://production.cf.rubygems.org`, but connect to `http://production.s3.rubygems.org` successfully. So I think my way is pretty obvious now, I just need to change the url `http://production.cf.rubygems.org` to `http://production.s3.rubygems.org` somewhere in ruby/gem package I've installed? But how can I edit it? 
Is it true? Sorry for asking such silly question, but I hope I've made it clear, and could you guys help me out?

Comment: Is that the verbatim output or did you redact the name to read `<name>`? Because otherwise you likely copied&pasted a recipe and are using it without understanding it ... just a guess.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to ruby, I'm just trying to install gem, and for examples when I run `sudo gem install rails` it threw me that error, could not find a valid gem?

Comment: What happens, when you call `gem sources`?. Maybe it helps if you add another source (Like `gem sources --add http://rubygems.org/`).